# How does alpineJS re-reder a template on data update?

Tags: alpine.js

How does AlpineJS re-render a template ?

```
<script>let contacts = [];</script>
<div x-data="{ persons: contacts }">
    <template x-for=" person in persons ">
        <div x-text=" person "></div>
    </template>            
    <button x-on:click="contacts.push('Jack'); persons = contacts; console.log(persons.length);">Click</button>
</div>
```

I was expecting the div to have multiple text of Jack on click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case/example `contacts` are out of Alpine's scope, once the component is initiated it's in it's own bubble, anything outside out the component scope `x-data` won't trigger a re-render.

If you change `contacts.push('Jack');` to `persons.push('Jack');`, that will trigger a re-render.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's not the most efficient way but I've had a similar problem, to resolve it I used the get function inspired from [this](https://alpinejs.dev/start-here#building-a-search-input).

My use case is the following:

JS:

```
get updatedState() {
      var config_state = [];
      #update your data here 
      return config_state;
}
```

HTML:

```
<template x-for="config in updatedState">
#Do what you want here
</template>
```

Each time your data changes, your loop will update the data

Comment: Doesn't `get updatedState` have to be inside some sort of object ?

Comment: You need to call this within another function like this: function blbl(){ return { get updatedState(){[...]}}}